# how to generate a corresponding table in db when I add a friendship model in AccountModel.cs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a new model `friendship` to store the users friendship status. I put this model in the AccountModel.cs file, and I marked it in the data context class. But after running this project, I find that the friendship model hasn't generated its reflection in the database. I hope anyone could help me out. The code is as follows:

```
[Table("Friendship")]
public class Friendship
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public string FS_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Users")] 
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Users")]
    public string FriendId { get; set; }

}

public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Friendship> Friendships { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx this should help you get started

Comment: @Yasser  I think I'm following the steps just as most entity framework tutorial told me to. I wondered if any unnoticable errors happened in my code, but in vs I can't trace it...

Comment: In code-first approach, when you add a new model, either you add table to db manually or EF will generate for you automatically but with a DbMigration tool. Are you using DbMigration?

Comment: @imannemati Oh, not really, you remind me. But I try to add a table manually.I just find that our team project doesn't install an entity framework package.